# How can i get Tabbar Item Button's Click event by clicking on TabbarItem button?

Tags: iphone

I have taken UITabbar on that i have used two buttons as TabItem.I want to perform two different Action by clicking on that two button so how can i get particular Action on clicking on particular Tabbar button.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You most likely want to take advantage of the UITabBarControllerDelegate, and then handle the didSelectViewController method.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

See here for more details: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 25):

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if(item.tag==1)
    {
        //your code
    }
    else
    {
       //your code
    }
}
```

You can use `UITabBarDelegate` for keeping the track of which button is pressed by assigning the `tag` or `title` for `title` you can use `item.title`.

Comment: This solution is good in a case where you are not using an actual TabBarController and simply want to capture some tab bar tap events in a normal view controller. Thanks!