# Navigating another screen when tabbar selected when user already logged in another tab-iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

My app has four tabs that displays different information.

In my second tab view controller i have one button lets name it as `button1` in that `button1` action i have navigated to `SignInViewController` screen and in my third tab view controller is `loginViewController`.

Here purpose of both `SignInViewController` and `loginViewController` screen is same i.e.,user can logged into the app in both the ViewController's.

Here what i want exactly is, if I am logged in `SignInViewController` then whenever I tap on third `TabBarItem` View Controller should directly navigated to next screen of `loginViewController` i.e.,to that next screen i have named it as `AccountViewController`. I have tried below code in `tabbarcontroller` class but its does not working.

Please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

       if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2){

        {

          if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"SigninStatus"] isEqualToString:@"SigninSuccess"]){

                UIStoryboard *story =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                LoginViewController *logInVc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:logInVc animated:YES];
            }
            else
            {

                UIStoryboard *story =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                AccountViewController *accountVc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AccountViewController"];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:accountVc animated:YES];

            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is it going to else condition? Did you check that?

Comment: yes it is going to else condition i kept break points also i have checked step by step coding wise  there is no problem but in simulator its doesn't navigating..

Comment: You mean when you tap on 3rd item from Tabbar "If user is already logged in" AccountViewcontroller should get pushed and in your case it is not getting pushed right?

Comment: yes sagar i have facing this problem since two days but till now i did not find any solution.

Comment: Update the answer, I think I got what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Is your `loginViewController` is embedded inside `UINavigationController`?

-If not than embed it inside `UINavigationController`

2.Create a *Push Segue* from `loginViewController` to `AccountViewController` e.g. segue identifier: `segueLoginToAccount`

3.Now when user click on 3rd tab bar item, create a check in `viewDidLoad` on `loginViewController`, to see whether user has already logged in or not:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"SigninStatus"] isEqualToString:@"SigninSuccess"]) {
        //already logged in, push to Account View
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueLoginToAccount" sender:nil];
    }//else user will stay on Login View
}
```

No need to use `tabBarController didSelectViewController:` method.

Answer (score 0):

First thing - If purpose of both viewcontroller is same then why different view controllers for both buttons ? You should use `same viewcontroller` for both cases.

Second thing you can store some `flag or status` in `NSUserDefaults` that contains information about user is loggedin or not.

Then just put `if - else` condition on button click that if user is logged in then `instantiate` next view controller instead of `loginVC` or if user is not logged in then show `loginVC` that's it.

**Update :**

As you asked in comment that you want this on tabbar's click then you should `subclass - UITabBarController and set it to your UITabBarController in iterface builder` and in that class you need to implement delegate method - `didSelectItem` and in this method check from userdefaults that user is logged in or not and set view controller accordingly!

Refer [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378652/open-viewcontroller-from-tab-like-in-instagram-camera-page-on-ios/30379403#30379403) for more details!

Comment: Thanks for ur response.its not about button now.I want this scenario when TabBarItem is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You need to put 3rd view controller inside NavigationController. This will enable navigation stack for the controller to push on.

> UIViewController* loginviewcontroller = [UIViewController alloc] init];
>
> UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
>   initWithRootViewController: loginviewcontroller];

Assign this navController in Tabbar.

e.g:

> NSMutableArray* viewControllersList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>
> [viewControllersList addObject: navController];
>
> [tabBarController setTabBarControllers: viewControllersList];

Via storyboard you can embed Navigation controller like this

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you Sagar for ur response.3rd view controller means where i have to? and where i have to place that code?

Comment: Updated answer with some more details.

Comment: you mean 3rd view controller means loginviewcontroller?

Comment: Yup its loginViewController. Updated answer for same.