# Set Action for UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

How can i set an `action` for my `UITabBarItem` ? Can i connect it from `storyboard` to code somehow? or programmatically? And if so how can it be done?

My hierarchy is `UITabBarController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `UITabBarItem`

Sorry for the noobish question but i really need an answer for this. And I couldn't find anything regarding this online.

Using Swift 3 and Xcode 8

Thank you!

## i tired Mannopson's Answer (didn't work):

```
class BarsViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


self.tabBarController?.delegate = self

        }

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
            if viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1 {
                self.tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
            }
        }
        }
                extension UITableView {
                func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
                    setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: animated)
                }
            }
```

## silentBob Answer Didn't Work for me :

```
class BarsViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate{


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
}

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1 {
            tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

## i also tried Tushar Sharma's answer and it didn't work as well.

What Im trying to do is when you are scrolled down in the `tableView` you will tap the current `Tabbaritem` the tableView Will scroll to top just like intagram.

Comment: Did you mean a UITabBarItem?

Comment: Yes!Sorry i will fix this.

Comment: Use a tag, and then you can detect which tab bar item is currently selected

Comment: Can help me with the code ? I have no idea how im gonna do this...

Comment: @Mannopson i would really appreciate the help

Comment: Do you know how to set the tag?

Comment: @Mannopson updated question thats what i tried from your answer i try something else all the time but i just can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

**Basically you do this:**

1) Make sure your class confirm to the UITabBarDelegate

2) Set tags in IB for each tab bar item

3) Implement the didSelectItem method, something like this:

```
 class yourclass: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
        func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
           if(item.tag == 1) {
       //your code for tab item 1
    }
    else if(item.tag == 2) {
       //your code for tab item 2
    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I will test it in a few hours and report back :)

Comment: @Newbie Questions No problem be sure to give tags in IB otherwise it will crash if you tried to access tags directly.

Comment: @Newbie Questions have you specified tags in storyboard?

Comment: yep i gave every tabbarbuttonitem a specific tab going from 1 to 4

Comment: I don't know and cant check at the moment. In a few hours i might be able to. @TusharSharma any idea why its not working?

Comment: @ Newbie Questions can you put a Breakpoint on this function and test what is happening ??

Comment: Firslty which function exactly? And secondly not right now but in a few hours. @TusharSharma

Comment: The code isn't breaking or crashing or anything the tab bar scroll to top function is just not working as i wanted it to @TusharSharma

Comment: @ Newbie questions Do this to scroll to top tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true).But with breakpoint debugging gets much easier.I just want to check is that delegate method is getting called successfully or not.

Comment: Understood. Will do it when i can @TusharSharma

Comment: i put breakpoints all over but nothing is showing in the debugger

Comment: @Newbie Questions is it getting to that delegate?

Comment: i seriously get nothing out of the debugger maybe explain more specifically how to set up the breakpoint? Maybe i did it wrong although i added every breakpoint available...

Comment: @Newbie Questions check this and confirm everythingis same.-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378652/open-viewcontroller-from-tab-like-in-instagram-camera-page-on-ios/30379403#30379403

Comment: The only thing different is i use tableviewcontroller and not viewcontroller @TusharSharma

Comment: Ok i didn't had the tabbarcontroller delegate let me try and add this.

Comment: because im using a uitableviewcontroller i cant implement uitabbarcontroller protocol...im trying to find a way to reference the tableview in my tableViewController in a new swift file i made and im struggling to do that.

Comment: Do you know a way to reference a tablview from another viewController in a different swift file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to setup `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol. Try this:

```
class YourClass: YourSuperClass, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1 {
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
    }
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I will try this as soon as i get home

Comment: i implemented this in my tableViewController code file.

Comment: Are you set the delegate to self in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yep. The delegate is set to self

Comment: You don't need any other scroll functions

Comment: Are you tried my suggestion? You've not implemented UITabBarControllerDelegate method yet. Take a look my answer. This is work. You don't need UITabBarDelegate method.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to scroll to top, there is a builtin system option for this, try tapping on status bar.

Edit:

Swift 3:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension UITableViewController : UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    public func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Swift 2:

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)


extension UITableViewController : UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Oh, that was a nice lunch :)

Here is an extension for UITableViewController you can use if you wish to scroll to top on every view controller, i'm still playing with it, but i think you can use it.

Comment: Yea i know but instagram has both methods tapping the status bar and the tabbaritem.... i want it as well.

Comment: Here, i've edited my answer, i think this should work for you. 
Also you have an option to use property instead of tags to get the right item in tabbar. Also scrollRectToVisible is an option.

Comment: can you translate to swift 2.2 ? I'm having troubles to translate that. will be helpful , thank you

Comment: Sure, but i'd advise you to switch to Swift 3 if you can. It won't go backwards, and Swift 4 is in progress already.

I think syntax was like this:

scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)

Comment: I know ... sadly i barely know swift 2.2 and thats what i started with , I'm the most comfortable with this syntax.... i will need a loot of help moving my project to Swift 4 :( im trying to learn by your answers and videos online . Thanks for the translation , i will try it now

Comment: You have some time until that, but it was quite a jump from 2 to 3. 
Swift 4 shouldn't be that much of a change, that is if you're jumping from Swift 3 ;)

Comment: Updated Question : this is what i have now and it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: There are a lot of sources for learning, here is a link of resources that one  guy put up https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/continuous-ios-learning-stefan-sut