# Tap UITabBarItem To Scroll To Top Like Instagram and Twitter

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrolltop, uitabbaritem

I'm having issues making this feature work and i would like to get some help.

My hierarchy is `TabBarController` -> `Navigation Controller` -> `TableViewController`

What i want is if you are on current tab and you scrolled down you will be able to tap the current View's `UITabBarItem` and you will be scrolled back to the top,Like Instagram and Twitter does for example.

I have tried many things right here :

[Older Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681013/set-action-for-uitabbaritem)

but sadly non of the answers did the job for me.

I would really appreciate any help about this manner ,
Thank you in advance!

## Here is my TableView`controller's Code :

```
import UIKit

class BarsViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate{

//TableView Data & non related stuff....

override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        self.searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        if tabBarIndex == 0 {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            let navigVC = viewController as? UINavigationController
            let finalVC = navigVC?.viewControllers[0] as? BarsViewController
            finalVC?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

        } 
    }

}
```

## TabBarController.Swift Code ( Code doesn't work ) :

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.delegate = self
}


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let viewControllers = viewControllers else { return false }
        if viewController == viewControllers[selectedIndex] {
            if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController {
                guard let topController = nav.viewControllers.last else { return true }
                if !topController.isScrolledToTop {
                    topController.scrollToTop()
                    return false
                } else {
                    nav.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        return true
    }

}
extension UIViewController {
    func scrollToTop() {
        func scrollToTop(view: UIView?) {
            guard let view = view else { return }

            switch view {
            case let scrollView as UIScrollView:
                if scrollView.scrollsToTop == true {
                    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
                    return
                }
            default:
                break
            }

            for subView in view.subviews {
                scrollToTop(view: subView)
            }
        }

        scrollToTop(view: view)
    }

    var isScrolledToTop: Bool {
        for subView in view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = subView as? UIScrollView {
                return (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok Just a minute....

Comment: I updated and added what i think is related if you want all code i can added it just let me know.... @AntonBelousov

Comment: You're not setting the delegate anywhere. You need to do in `viewDidLoad`: `delegate = self`

Comment: Also, in the storyboard is the class for the tab bar controller set to `TabBarController `?

Comment: yes, its connected in the story board to that class.

Comment: So just need to do `delegate = self` in the `viewDidLoad()` of `TabBarController`

Comment: i addd that a long time ago and it didn't help @JackChamberlain

Comment: Here (https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f4ad4933dcc7ae368645319356922b0c20170414145238/b34d17) is a very hastily done, working example of my answer using the same view controller hierarchy as your question

Comment: you use ViewController , i use tableViewController @JackChamberlain

Comment: @JackChamberlain can you make it work on a tableViewController?

Comment: @JackChamberlain i'v just tried and your code has **NO** effect on `TableViewController` **BUT DOES** on `UITableView`! so my question now is this even **possible** to do it for `tableViewController`?

Comment: Yes, see the update to my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141732/discussion-between-jack-chamberlain-and-newbie-questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, this should work:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard let viewControllers = viewControllers else { return false }
    if viewController == viewControllers[selectedIndex] {
        if let nav = viewController as? ZBNavigationController {
            guard let topController = nav.viewControllers.last else { return true }
            if !topController.isScrolledToTop {
                topController.scrollToTop()
                return false
            } else {
                nav.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            return true
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

and then...

```
extension UIViewController {
    func scrollToTop() {
        func scrollToTop(view: UIView?) {
            guard let view = view else { return }

            switch view {
            case let scrollView as UIScrollView:
                if scrollView.scrollsToTop == true {
                    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
                    return
                }
            default:
                break
            }

            for subView in view.subviews {
                scrollToTop(view: subView)
            }
        }

        scrollToTop(view: view)
    }

    // Changed this

    var isScrolledToTop: Bool {
        if self is UITableViewController {
            return (self as! UITableViewController).tableView.contentOffset.y == 0
        }
        for subView in view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = subView as? UIScrollView {
                return (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

There's a bit extra in this function so that if the `UIViewController` is already at the top it will pop to the previous controller

Comment: What do you mean it will "pop" to the previous controller? and do i put this code in my `tableViewController` or `TabBarController`?

Comment: In your UITabBarController. But make sure to put the `UIViewController` extension outside of a class. Popping just means that if there is a previous view controller in the navigation stack it will slide back to it, probably not necessary but a nice little addition

Comment: Ah i see , really nice . I'm trying your answer now.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying: "`Expected declaration`" in the last `return true` of the func : `func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {`

Comment: You probably have an extra `{` or `}` somewhere

Comment: fixed it ... instead of 3 - `}` between the two return true there should be 2 and another - `}` after the return true. Running and testing now .

Comment: Ah, my bad. I removed an extra `if` condition for the answer so just remove the last `}` before `return true`

Comment: sadly the code isn't working for me....i will upload code to question to show you what i have.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code in your TabViewController:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
    if tabBarIndex == 0 {

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        let navigVC = viewController as? UINavigationController
        let finalVC = navigVC?.viewControllers[0] as? YourVC
        finalVC?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

    } 
}
```

Also, your TabViewController should inherit from UITabBarControllerDelegate

[image]

final code:

```
import UIKit

class tabViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        if tabBarIndex == 0 {

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            let navigVC = viewController as? UINavigationController
            let finalVC = navigVC?.viewControllers[0] as? YourVC
            finalVC?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

        } 
    }


}
```

Remember to change tabBarIndex and set **self.delegate = self** in viewDidLoad

Comment: Try making new class for example (class tabViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate), connect it with your TabBarController in your storyboard and put the function inside this class.

Comment: Remember to change tabBarIndex

Comment: Your code is making the view to scroll or it is not at all scrolling?

Comment: its not scrolling at all @Prabhu.Somasundaram

Comment: @Phyber changed index to 1-4 ( amount of tabs i have ) and still nothing worked. maybe you can write something by tags? i set tags 1-4 maybe that will do?

Comment: Do you have this line of code ?:  self.delegate = self

Comment: Can you show us your storyboard please? This code works just fine for me.

Comment: Can you change the scroll position to .Middle. Just to make sure your code has effect.?

Comment: In tabviewcontroller just put         self.delegate = self, In VIEWDIDLOAD
just to be on safer side?

Comment: @Prabhu.Somasundaram Error: `BarsViewController` (my tableviewcontroller)  `has no member 'delegate'`......its a controller so the delegate is already set to self am i wrong? + i will try the .Middle now.

Comment: it should be in TabBarController's viewDidLoad

Comment: and your class should inherit from UITabBarControllerDelegate

Comment: @Phyber i tried adding `self.delegate = self` to my tableViewController's `ViewDidLoad` and i get the error : `BarsViewController has no member 'delegate'` still....

Comment: You have to put self.delegate = self inside viewDidLoad inside TabBarController. Does conform to the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol, because you have to put the function as I mentioned inside TabBarController.

Comment: I have `self.delegate = self` in the `view did load` already... it still doesn't work... **no matter how many people will help me i think i will never get this to work** .... :\

Comment: Can u send us ur project ?

Answer (score 3):

**You have just to create a file `TabBarViewController` with this code :**

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let viewControllers = viewControllers else { return false }
        if viewController == viewControllers[selectedIndex] {
            if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController {
                guard let topController = nav.viewControllers.last else { return true }
                if !topController.isScrolledToTop {
                    topController.scrollToTop()
                    return false
                } else {
                    nav.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func scrollToTop() {
        func scrollToTop(view: UIView?) {
            guard let view = view else { return }

            switch view {
            case let scrollView as UIScrollView:
                if scrollView.scrollsToTop == true {
                    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
                    return
                }
            default:
                break
            }

            for subView in view.subviews {
                scrollToTop(view: subView)
            }
        }

        scrollToTop(view: view)
    }

    var isScrolledToTop: Bool {
        if self is UITableViewController {
            return (self as! UITableViewController).tableView.contentOffset.y == 0
        }
        for subView in view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = subView as? UIScrollView {
                return (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

**And then in your storyboard, set custom class `TabBarController` like this :**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Great examples! I've tried some things also and I guess this small piece of code for our delegate is all we need:

```
extension AppDelegate: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    // Scroll to top when corresponding view controller was already selected and no other viewcontrollers are pushed
    guard tabBarController.viewControllers?[tabBarController.selectedIndex] == viewController,
          let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController, navigationController.viewControllers.count == 1,
          let topViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first,
          let scrollView = topViewController.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView }) as? UIScrollView else {
        return true
    }

    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)), animated: true)
    return false
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I just had to implement this and was surprised to find out it wasn't as easy as I thought it would be. This is how I implemented it:

A few notes on my application's setup

- The MainTabBarcontroller is our root view controller and we generally access it from the UISharedApplication.
- Our navigation structure is MainTabBarController -> Nav Controller -> Visible View Controller

The main issue I found with implementing this is I only wanted to scroll to the top if I was already on the first screen in the tab bar but once you try to make this check from `tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)` you've already lost a reference to the view controller that was visible before you tapped it. It is also a problem to compare view controllers when you're switching tabs since the visible view controller might be in another tab.

So I created a property in my TabBar class to hold a reference to the `previousTopVC` and created a protocol to help me set this property from the currently visible VC.

```
protocol TopScreenFindable {
    func setVisibleViewController()
}

extension TopScreenFindable where Self: UIViewController {
    func setVisibleViewController() {
        guard let tabController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarController else { return }
        tabController.previousTopVC = self
    }
}
```

I then called conformed to this protocol and setVisibleViewController from the View Controllers' viewDidAppear and now had a reference to the previous visible VC when any screen showed up.

I created a delegate for my MainTabBarController class

```
protocol MainTabBarDelegate: class {
    func firstScreenShouldScrollToTop()
}
```

Then called it from the UITabBarControllerDelegate method

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        guard let navController = viewController as? UINavigationController, let firstVC = navController.viewControllers.first, let previousVC = previousTopController else { return }
        if firstVC == previousVC {
            mainTabBarDelegate?.firstScreenShouldScrollToTop()
        }
    }
```

And in the First View Controllers conformed to the MainTabBarDelegate

```
extension FirstViewController: MainTabBarDelegate {
    func firstScreenShouldScrollToTop() {
        collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: collectionView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
    }
```

I set the `tabBar.mainTabBarDelegate = self` on the FirstViewController's viewDidAppear so that the delegate was set every time the screen showed up. If I did it on viewDidLoad it wouldn't work when switching tabs.

A couple things I didn't like about my approach.

- Having a reference to the tab bar in my view controllers just so it can set itself as its delegate.
- Making every relevant screen in the app conform to the `TopScreenFindable` protocol