# iOS UITabBar position and items

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I've created a view and I added a UITabBar dragged from Storyboard.
The problems I'm facing are the following. I'm trying to add more items to the UITabBar from storyboard but can't seem to find any information of how to do that. Any pointers would be appreciated
I'm not using UITabBarController.

Is it possible to decide where to place the tab bar. If I want it in the middle of the screen for testing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the steps :

1. Add a Tab bar to your View controller .
2. Drag a tab bar item and add it to you tab bar like so[image]

And you are done; By default the tab bar will be added to the bottom of the screen

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I add navigation when I select one of the tab bar items?

Comment: @user1185305 what do you mean by navigation ?

Comment: I add a new item to the tab bar. Now I want that item to show something when selected. Either a new page of something else. How can I do that?

Comment: @user1185305 please if my answer helped you mark it as accepted, here is a reference on how to implement tab bar actions http://stackoverflow.com/a/11772086/2591165 , but keep in mind that you have to set the tab bar delegate as your view controller